# User-defined Type not defined windows 10

Tags: xml, excel, vba, domdocument

I have this sub that gets weather information from a weather API. It works on Windows 7 computers but not Windows 10. I get a "User-defined type not defined" error and it highlights the `Dim Req As New XMLHTTP` line. I have tried to change the DOMDocument to DOMDocument60 and Ive tried to make sure the MicrosoftXML V6.0 is checked.

```
Public Sub GetWeather(APIurl As String, sted As String)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim city As String
    Dim omraade As String
    Dim Req As New XMLHTTP
    Dim Weather As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim wShape As Shape
    Dim thisCell As Range
    Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60

    i = 0
    omraade = ""
    omraade = sted

    Select Case omraade
        Case "Area1"
            i = 4
        Case "Area2"
            i = 6
        Case "Area3"
            i = 8
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
    End Select

    Req.Open "GET", "" & APIurl & "", False
    Req.Send
    Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText

    For Each Weather In Resp.getElementsByTagName("current_condition")

        Set thisCell = ws.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i))
        Set wShape = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, thisCell.Left, thisCell.Top, thisCell.Width, thisCell.Height)

        wShape.Fill.UserPicture Weather.ChildNodes(4).Text 'img

        Cells(3, i).Value = "" & Weather.ChildNodes(7).Text * 0.28 & " m/s" 'windspeedkmph
        Cells(4, i).Value = Weather.ChildNodes(9).Text 'Direction
        Cells(5, i).Value = Weather.ChildNodes(1).Text & " C"  'observation time
    Next Weather

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in the project references for missing items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Microsoft XML v6.0 library properly referenced in Tools, References, the appropriate call is,

```
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you! Do you mind explaining why I need to do that? :)

Comment: The 'type' of the var described within the Microsoft XML v6.0 library is not XMLHTTP, it is MSXML2.XMLHTTP60. In sort, it is a version thing.

Answer (score 2):

I changed from XML 6.0 to XML 3.0 in Tools, References and now works on both Windows 7 and Windows 10...

Comment: What's the advantage of switching back to XML 3.0 when the accepted answer works in XML 6.0?

Comment: Less testing required if you are not changing the code.